# left justification problem

Tags: alignment

just trying it out to see if it will be easy enough to write my thesis (not due for a long while). I wrote the following code and got the following compilation.

I don't understand why some of the headings are not aligned the same.  Thanks
[image]

Comment: Because they aren't headings.  `\textbf` just makes the text bold, it doesn't make a heading.  Each of your `\textbf` commands starts a new paragraph and is hence indented.  If you don't want that then stick in a `\noindent' without an empty line in between.   There are better ways of achieving what you want, but to get that kind of help you should stick in a minimum working example instead of a picture of part of your code.

Comment: please always show code as text so people can debug it and use it to test answers, not as an image, but you should avoid all use of `\\ `  `\noindent` and explicit spaces, but instead use sectioning commands such as `\section*{Research Funding}`,  the blank line after `\noindent`  for example means that it does not suppress indentation (but you should never need that command)